# Leer Archivo XML con Python

Tags: python, xml

Cómo puedo leer este archivo...???

a.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Data>
  <Dependiente>
    <Id>123654</Id>
    <Nombre>Pedro</Nombre>
    <Edad>36</Edad>
  </Dependiente>
  <Dependiente>
    <Id>236958</Id>
    <Nombre>Juan</Nombre>
    <Edad>27</Edad>
  </Dependiente>
</Data>
```

Necesito obtener algo como lo que sigue...

Dependientes = [[123654, 'Pedro', 36], [236958, 'Juan', 27]]

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Hola, recuerda agregar lo que trataste o investigaste por favor, revisar [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Lo habitual para leer ficheros XML es el módulo `lxml` (no viene preinstalado).

```
from lxml import etree
with open("a.xml") as f:
  data = etree.parse(f)
```

El estándar para extraer información de un XML una vez leído, es usar el lenguaje de consulta XPath que te permite hacer peticiones con un cierto lenguaje de selección que devuelvan sólo la información que estés buscando.

La biblioteca `lxml` soporta XPath. Hay muchas formas posibles de usarlo. Veamos un par de ellas:

1. Seleccionar todos los nodos de tipo `Dependiente`, y después iterar sobre cada uno de ellos para extraer (usando de nuevo XPath relativo) la información que quieres sobre cada uno de ellos, para ir creando una lista con esa información. La sintaxis es un poco farragosa debido a que XPath siempre devuelve como resultados listas, aún si éstas tienen un solo elemento, por lo que en ocasiones es necesario utilizar `[0]` sobre el resultado para quedarse con ese elemento.

   ```py
   result = []
   for elem in p.xpath("//Dependiente"):
   id = int(elem.xpath("Id/text()")[0])
   nombre = elem.xpath("Nombre/text()")[0]
   edad = int(elem.xpath("Edad/text()")[0])
   result.append([id, nombre, edad])
   ```
2. Seleccionar todos los nodos de tipo `Id`, `Nombre`  y `Edad`, con independencia de dónde aparezcan dentro del XML (suponiendo implícitamente que sólo van a aparecer dentro de elementos de tipo `Dependiente`:

   ```py
   ids = [int(id) for id in elem.xpath("//Id/text()")]
   nombres = elem.xpath("//Nombre/text()")
   edades = [int(edad) for edad in elem.xpath("//Edad/text()")]
   ```

   Ahora hay que juntar estas tres listas para crear la que buscas. Nos ayudamos de la función `zip()`:

   ```py
   result = [list(x) for x in zip(ids, nombres, edades)]
   ```

Por cualquiera de los dos métodos el resultado es:

```
[[123654, 'Pedro', 36], [236958, 'Juan', 27]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Imaginando que tu archivo XML se llame "dependientes.xml" y que estés usando la versión 3 de Python, podrías hacerlo con este código:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Abrimos y parseamos el fichero XML
tree = ET.parse('dependientes.xml')

# Obtenemos el elemento raíz del fichero XML,
# es decir, la etiqueta <Data>
data = tree.getroot()

# Creamos el array vacío que contendrá los
# datos agrupados de los dependientes
lista_dependientes = []

# Iteramos sobre cada dependiente del fichero
for dependiente in data:
    # Almacenamos en una lista todos los
    # atributos de un dependiente
    lista_atributos = [atributo.text for atributo in dependiente]

    # Almacenamos los atributos del dependiente
    # en la lista de dependientes
    lista_dependientes.append(lista_atributos)

# Mostramos el resultado
print(lista_dependientes)
```

Esto sacaría como resultado la lista de listas que quieres, aunque todos los elementos serían `strings`. Para convertir el ID y la edad a número entero, podrías hacerlo a posteriori o in situ, según precises.

Asimismo, una versión más corta del código que he escrito arriba sería la siguiente, haciendo más uso aún de las conocidas "[List Comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)":

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = ET.parse('dependientes.xml').getroot()

lista_dependientes = [
    [atributo.text for atributo in dependiente]
    for dependiente in data
]

print(lista_dependientes)
```